# how to do java counter i++ in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i want to do counter variable, im using ireport 3.4.2

in java we can simply do like i++ to increament. how can i do t in iReport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer might be right also, but i didnt tried it. I try to created variable and set the calculation field "count" and then set the variable expression correctly based counter factor. it works.

Answer (score 1):

`$V{variable1}++` is absolutely legal in iReport, as long as variable1 is **Integer** and the Calculation is **Count** or **Incremental Count**