# how to do variable + 1 in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i want to do line no in different band area. example, in group band i want it to appear

1.
 2.
 and the next band area, such as detail band, i want it continue
 3.
 4.

i dont it reset. how???

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do java counter i++ in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456708/how-to-do-java-counter-i-in-ireport)

Answer (score 3):

Create a group_COUNT variable. Make it an **Integer**, give it Calculation type **Count**, Reset type **Report**, Increment type **Group** and select the Increment Group. The Variable Expression should be `$V{group_COUNT}++`.  Drop it to your Group zone and it should increment each time the group changes.

Comment: I used as `new Integer($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()+1)` in variable's expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a group and you are using the detail band (means in detail band you have to print the valueis as you said ) then use the report generated variable like (your groupname_count) which gives the valuu like 123 and next band 3,4  as query found the records in the detail band.
or 
if you have created the group and you have to print the nor as 1, 2 like this and for next group records 3,4
then create one variable class name is maths big decimal, calculation count, reset type your group nameincrement type none,variable expersion(in which the field which have alws value display) place there initial value expression is 0.